# Text disappearing behind container

Tags: html, css, text

I have a problem where my text is disappearing after adding a sibling to a container. The text was there but for some reason now after adding a sibling element, the text missing. I just noticed after doing the snippet the text is behind its container. And number 2, the width of .container is not what it should be in the snippet. The width is still working on my computer, but still..

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}



body {
    background-color: green;
}


html, 
body {
  height: 100%;

}


header {
 
 height: 20%;
}

#subnav {

display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
margin: 0;
flex-flow: row wrap;
border-radius: 4px;
justify-content: flex-start;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
height: 5%;

 
}



.container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
 
}






.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    order: 1;
    //flex: 1 20%;
    width: 25%;
}



.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    flex: 2 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: center;
 order: 3;
 width: 15%;
 flex: 1 50%;

}

div.list{
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 300%;;

}



.right .list{
    // text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
}






#footer{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
list-style: none;
height: 150px;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: orange;
}









#nav li a{
 color: white;
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: courier;
}

#nav li {
 list-style: none;
  
}


#nav ul{
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 margin: 0;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  
  
}


div.logo {
  
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 30%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}


#bigwrap{
  height: 100%;
}






.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 70vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.container p {
  
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  
}

.container img {
  
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  
}


.left, .middle, .right{
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}



.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    flex: 2 20%;
}




.right .list{
    height: auto;
}



.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
}


.right .headbox{
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
        <div id="bigwrap">
    
           <div id="subnav">

            home home home
           <div>

 
    
     <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
         <img src="filler.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">
            <img src="filler.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">
            
            
           
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="box">
              <p>
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
              </p>


            </div>

              <div class="box">
              <p>
                Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text

             </div>
            
            <div class="box">
            <p>
               Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
            </p>
              


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div class="headbox">
                <h3>Visit Us</h3>
              
            </div>

            <div class="list">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Plan</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>

                   </ul>
            </div>


            
            

        </div>
    </div>

  

 </div>
```

Comment: Would you create a fiddle or codepen for testing?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/9pvab92z/

Answer (score 1):

The text is there, but it have color-white, and it is on background-color:white. So it is invisible. Change color.

Comment: No that's subnav's text, not container's. Container's text is black and is partially visible behind the container.

Comment: I answer You in another post, so u have a snippet right now

Answer (score 1):

Look, when You change bg-color of container the text is visible. The wrong thing is You set the color of text, and the color of background to the same color, white.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}



body {
    background-color: green;
}


html, 
body {
  height: 100%;

}


header {
 
 height: 20%;
}

#subnav {

display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
margin: 0;
flex-flow: row wrap;
border-radius: 4px;
justify-content: flex-start;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
height: 5%;

 
}



.container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  background-color: gray;
 
}






.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    order: 1;
    //flex: 1 20%;
    width: 25%;
}



.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    flex: 2 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: center;
 order: 3;
 width: 15%;
 flex: 1 50%;

}

div.list{
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 300%;;

}



.right .list{
    // text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
}






#footer{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
list-style: none;
height: 150px;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: orange;
}









#nav li a{
 color: white;
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: courier;
}

#nav li {
 list-style: none;
  
}


#nav ul{
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 margin: 0;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  
  
}


div.logo {
  
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 30%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}


#bigwrap{
  height: 100%;
}






.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 70vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
    background-color:gray;
}

.container p {
  
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  
}

.container img {
  
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  
}


.left, .middle, .right{
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}



.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    flex: 2 20%;
}




.right .list{
    height: auto;
}



.list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.headbox h3{
    color: orange;
}


.right .headbox{
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
        <div id="bigwrap">
    
           <div id="subnav">

            home home home
           <div>

 
    
     <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
         <img src="filler.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">
            <img src="filler.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">
            
            
           
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="box">
              <p>
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
              </p>


            </div>

              <div class="box">
              <p>
                Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text

             </div>
            
            <div class="box">
            <p>
               Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
                 Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text
            </p>
              


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div class="headbox">
                <h3>Visit Us</h3>
              
            </div>

            <div class="list">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Plan</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>

                   </ul>
            </div>


            
            

        </div>
    </div>

  

 </div>
```